# how many pairs differ in one value from another

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

Assume I have a family of sets $X=\{X_1,X_2,...,X_m\}$ each set $X_i\in X$ has $n$ elements $\{x^i_1,x^i_2,...,x^i_n\}$. Let $Z$ be the cartesian product of $X$. Let $z^{\downarrow V}$ be the projection of $z\in Z$ into $V\subset X$. For example if $X=\{X_1,X_2\}$ and $z=(x^1_i,x^2_j)$ then $z^{\downarrow X_1}=x^1_i$

I would like to find the number of all unordered pairs $P=\{(z_1,z_2)|z_1,z_2\in Z \ \wedge z_1^{\downarrow V}=z_2^{\downarrow V}\}$ where $|V|=|X|-1$ . In other words, I would like to find the number of all pairs $(z_1,z_2)$ that differ only on one value for one set $X_i\in X$.

For example if $X=\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,y_2\}$ then I will have: 
$(x_1y_1,x_1y_2)\\(x_1y_1,x_2y_1)\\(x_1y_2,x_2y_2)\\(x_2y_1,x_2y_2)$

How many pairs having such property? What about when they are ordered?

Here is what I know from trying: when $n=2$, I have $m2^{m-1}$ pairs.

Comment: What do you mean by "when they are ordered?"

Comment: @RossMillikan when $(z_1,z_2)\not=(z_2,z_1)$ i.e $(x_1y_1,x_1y_2)$ and $(x_1y_2,x_1y_1)$

Comment: Then you just multiply my answer by $2$ for the two orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A given pair can have the $x$ coordinate changed in $n-1$ ways or the $y$ coordinate changed in $n-1$ ways, so is related to $2n-2$ other pairs.  As there are $n^2$ pairs we have $\frac 12n^2(2n-2)=n^2(n-1)$ relations.  The factor $\frac 12$ comes because each relation got counted twice.

If you consider the relations ordered, the same count applies but you don't divide by $2$, so you get $2n^2(n-1)$

If you have $k$ sets of $n$ elements and ask for pairs of $k$ tuples that differ in one coordinate, a given tuple can pair with $k(n-1)$ other tuples. There are $n^k$ tuples, so the number of unordered pairs is $n^kk(n-1)/2$  Again, for ordered pairs, multiply by $2$, getting $n^kk(n-1)$

Comment: Thanks Ross does this only work for two sets? Assume I have three binary sets ($n=2$), According to this, I will get 8 however there are 12 unordered pairs.

Comment: For three sets, are you making triples and requiring that two of the elements match?

Comment: Yes.. I should made it general in the post.

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look.